# TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, django, testing

i got error message when trying to run the test of django
this is my code for the model file

```
   class MountPoint(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       backend = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=DEFAULT_BACKEND)
       path = models.CharField(max_length=300)

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
```

and here is the class i put in test

```
  class MountPoint(TestCase):
      def create_mountpoint(self):
          name = "test"
          backend = "test"
          path = user_root
          return MountPoint(name, backend, path)

      def test_mountpoint_creation(self):
          m = self.create_mountpoint()
          self.assertTrue(isinstance(m, MountPoint))
          self.assertEqual(m.__unicode(), m.name)
```

and the error message i got is below. it said i have more inputs than expected.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xihui/Documents/WebProgramming/django/ece264site/filesystem/tests.py", line 18, in test_mountpoint_creation
    m = self.create_mountpoint()
  File "/Users/xihui/Documents/WebProgramming/django/ece264site/filesystem/tests.py", line 15, in create_mountpoint
    return MountPoint(name, backend, path)
TypeError: **init**() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

---

Ran 1 test in 0.009s

FAILED (errors=1)

Comment: The name of the test class shadows the name of your model class, so when you try to instantiate a model instance, it actually tries to create a new instance of the test class, which takes different args obviously. Rename your test class to `TestMountPoint`

Comment: by the way, DEFAULT_BACKEND = 'filesystem.backend.HDWrapper.DirectionHDWrapper,filesystem.backend.HDWrapper.DocumentHDWrapper'

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use keyword args:

```
return MountPoint(name=name, backend=backend, path=path)
```